# Automation Testing with Ranorex

Tags: php, testing, automation, ranorex

I am testing my PHP web application using the Ranorex automation tool. Whenever I record my test case, it is recording perfectly but when I play my test case it stops (sometimes it hangs) at the middle and fails my test case.

What is the reason that is creating this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The good way to automate is to write code **without using recorder.**
There are some reasons of it:

1. recording unnecessary steps
2. saving elements to repository by wrong
   attribute. As usual there are automation id and regex of text or
   caption of element. For dynamically changeable elements this doesn't
   fit.
3. different types of elements requires different types of methods
   to wait and validate them.

In this way, **I recommend you** to watch the [screencast of Ranorex Team](http://www.ranorex.com/support/screencasts.html).
There are 5 videos about everything you should know about UI Mapping.

**According to you exceptions and errors in comments:**

1. *"...ATagPrintReport3' does not match the specified value (actual='False', expected='True')"* 
   It means that Ranorex recorded element ATagPrintReport3 with value of some bool attribute. Of cource, the value of element will change, so the right way is to identify element with the attribute that will never change (uniqueId, name, class and other).
2. *Failed to find item 'updtaed_cpt_imsRepository.OpeningInventoryStockValueJpg.ButtonOK'. No element found for path '/form[@title~'^Opening\ Inventory\ Stock\ V']/button[@accessiblename='OK']' within 1m.*
   This error can be the result of very fast dynamically changeable element, the wrong path of element, it could be presented in dom but could not be visible. 
   The best way to know what's wrong is to use breakpoints and step-to-step debuging.

In my opinion the path for ButtonOK will be better if it looks like:
*'/form[@title~'Opening\ Inventory\ Stock']/button[@name='OK']'*

3. *No element found for path '/form[@title='Reading Untagged Document']/?/?/button[@text='&Cancel']' within 1m.*
   It is the same to p.2
   In this example, the path will be better:

*'/form[@title='Reading Untagged Document']//button[@name='&Cancel']'*

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a error message in the report. 
What does this message say?

I suggest checking if the elements can be recognized uniquely by Ranorex and if the webpage is fully loaded.
You can use the following code snippet in order to wait until the webpage is fully loaded.

```
WebDocument webDocument = "/dom[@caption='Your Test Page']"; 
webDocument.WaitForDocumentLoaded();
```

Concerning your second question, a video how to work with data connector can be found on the Ranorex website directly:
[Data-Driven Test Automation with Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/support/screencasts.html#c3896)

Comment: 'updtaed_cpt_imsRepository.CPTInventroySystem.ATagPrintReport3' does not match the specified value (actual='False', expected='True'). This is the error which is shown on the report result

Comment: another error is 'updtaed_cpt_imsRepository.OpeningInventoryStockValueJpg.ButtonOK' does not match the specified value (Failed to find item 'updtaed_cpt_imsRepository.OpeningInventoryStockValueJpg.ButtonOK'. No element found for path '/form[@title~'^Opening\ Inventory\ Stock\ V']/button[@accessiblename='OK']' within 1m.).

Comment: third error No element found for path '/form[@title='Reading Untagged Document']/?/?/button[@text='&Cancel']' within 1m.

Comment: It seems that simply the path to the element is not correct. Open the external Ranorex Spy tool, track the element and compare it with the RxPath within the repository.

Comment: @user1982826: How can i wait for WPF Form to get loaded in similar to webdocument load in the above code??